# el codigo debe de leer un archivo tipo .txt y ponerlo en cifrado cesar, el problema es que me quita los espacios

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
r=2
while r==2:

    print("1. Cifrar \n")
    print("2. Decifrar\n")
    res = pos=int(input("Elige una opcion de las anteriores \n =>"))

    ar = open ('prueba.txt','r') #archivo que lee
    G = ar.read()
    print(G)# imprime texto que existe en el archivo




    alfa="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    k = pos=int(input("Numero de caracteres que deseas recorrer =>"))

    cipher = "" 
    for c in G:
            if c in alfa:


                if res==1:
                   cipher += alfa [(alfa.index(c)+k)%(len(alfa))]


                if res==2:
                    cipher += alfa [(alfa.index(c)-k)%(len(alfa))]

    print(cipher )
    print("1. Si")
    print("2. No")
    r= pos=int(input("¿Quiere salir? >>>"))
    if r==1:
        r==r-1
```

Comment: Hola Maico, ¿Qué quieres decir con "me quita los espacios"? Tu código también cifra los espacios porque están incluidos en tu cadena `alpha`, por ejemplo un espacio pasará a ser una "e" si ciframos con 5 desplazamientos. Si quieres que los espacios no sean tocados al cifrar/descifrar deberás eliminarlo de la cadena `alpha` y añadirlo a `cipher` tal cual. ¿Que ocurre con el resto de caracteres como signos de interrogación, exclamación, números, etc? Ahora simplemente los ignoras.

Answer (score 1):

Una variación sobre tu código para que los espacios (y otros caracteres) queden tal cual, podría ser tener en una variable un string que contenga todos los caracteres a respetar, y copiar a `cipher` el caracter actual si está entre ellos. Es decir:

```py
    alfa="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    cipher = ""
    no_tocar = " .,¿?!¡:;()"
    for c in G:
       if c in no_tocar:
           cipher += c
       elif c in alfa:
           # ... el resto igual
```

Otro detalle, no cierras el fichero `ar`. Precisamente para no olvidar ese tipo de detalles se recomienda usar un contexto, es decir:

```py
    with open('prueba.txt', 'r') as ar: 
        G = ar.read()
```

El fichero se cierra automáticamente al salir del bloque `with`.

Un último detalle relacionado con la eficiencia, en código que tenga que construir una cadena letra a letra (o palabra a palabra) es preferible usar listas intermedias en lugar del operador `+=` sobre la cadena.

Es decir, `cipher` sería una lista inicialmente vacía (`cipher=[]`) a la cual vas añadiendo letras (`cipher.append(letra)`). Al final del bucle `cipher` será una lista con las letras ya convertidas, a partir de la cual generas la cadena resultado con `cipher = "".join(cipher)`. Esto es más rápido que usar el operador de concatener en cada iteración.